# how to get real time data and pass to jquery flot

Tags: jquery

I have a java class ( Test ) with a public method which returns a hashmap
Each entry in the hashmap is a (x,y) co-ordinate on the graph.

I am using JQuery flot to plot the graph. How do I call the Java class from JSP and 
pass the value to Jquery to plot the graph.

Can I call a Java class method on the server side from Ajax on the client side by passing parameters and get text as response

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think for what you want to do, the best framework is the [Direct Web Remoting Toolkit](http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/index.html) which allows to transparently export Java classes and call Java methods from JavaScript.